# align both top and bottom svg text vertical

Tags: svg, vertical-alignment

I have a paragraph written by svg as follows:

[image: svg source code]

Can you tell me how to align the content for both top and bottom
it will look like this:

[image: rendered output]

Comment: Your markup should be in the question as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes:
Just make, 
glyph-orientation-vertical:90

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <svg height="800" width="100%">
        <text x="500" y="50" font-size="22" text-anchor="inherit" style="writing-mode:tb; glyph-orientation-vertical:90">
            asdsd sdasadsa sad sad sadas sad
        </text> 

        <text x="470" y="50" font-size="22" text-anchor="inherit" style="writing-mode:tb; glyph-orientation-vertical:90">
            asdsd sdasadsa sad sad sadas sad
        </text> 

        <text x="440" y="50" font-size="22" text-anchor="inherit" style="writing-mode:tb; glyph-orientation-vertical:90">
            asdsd sdasadsa sad sad sadas sad
        </text> 

        <text x="410" y="50" font-size="22" text-anchor="inherit" style="writing-mode:tb; glyph-orientation-vertical:90">
            asdsd sdasadsa sad sad sadas sad
        </text> 

        <text x="380" y="50" font-size="22" text-anchor="inherit" style="writing-mode:tb; glyph-orientation-vertical:90">
            asdsd sdasadsa sad sad sadas sad
        </text> 

        <text x="350" y="50" font-size="22" text-anchor="inherit" style="writing-mode:tb; glyph-orientation-vertical:90">
            asdsd sdasadsa sad sad sadas sad
        </text> 
        

    </svg>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thank for your answer but i want to align the top margin and bottom margin